# odbc_prepare for procedure with datetime input parameters

Tags: php, sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures, odbc

Somewhat new to odbc_prepare statements and am having an issue when trying to execute a stored procedure that requires datetime input parameters.

If I am to execute using odbc without using the prepared statement as displayed below I have no issue...

```
$dblink = db_connect();
$query = "EXEC dbo.[ProcedureName] '" . $dateinput . "'";
odbc_exec($dblink, $query);
```

Using the odbc_prepare I'm getting an error (only for procedures with DateTime inputs parameters). Example below...

```
function execute_db($dblink, $query, $params){
   $n = sizeof($params);
   for($i=0; $i<$n; $i++){
        if($i != 0){
            $query = $query . ', ?';
        }
        else{
            $query  = $query . ' ?';
        }
    }

    $statement = odbc_prepare($dblink, $query);
    odbc_execute($statement, $params);

    return $statement;
}

$dblink = db_connect();
$query = "EXEC dbo.[ProcedureName]";
$params = array($dateinput);

$result = execute_db($dblink, $query, $params);
```

This returns the following error:

> Warning: odbc_execute(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver]Invalid character value for cast specification, SQL state 22005
>   in SQLExecute

The date string I'm passing in is in 'mm/dd/yyyy' format and works fine without using prepare.  Is there a workaround for this other than changing the stored procedure's input type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the proper ODBC syntax for calling a procedure and use the proper syntax for date times and it might get you further. The call syntax is {call procname(arguments)}. The datetime syntax is {ts ''} - see [Date, Time, and Timestamp Escape Sequences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [ODBC Datetime Format](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms190234%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Strange thing here, I did try using the CALL prior to posting this and I would be getting the error:  Invalid parameter number, SQL state S1093...  I did however switch the DateTime format in php to date(Y-m-d H:i:s.u) using my original execute_db function and it works.  Marking this as answered, if you happen to have any info on the CALL error that'd be helpful!

Comment: You need to use '{call procname(?)}' and bind your date a parameter 1.

Comment: Yeah that's what I tried and got that S1093 error: CALL Procedure(?) with array('yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.u'), so I switched back to the EXEC.  EXEC now works but I understand it's not the proper syntax.  Trying to figure out why but for now at least it's working I guess. @bohica