# How to correctly prepare and execute an odbc connection

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

I am getting the following error when trying to prepare and execute a statement:

> Invalid character value for cast specification, SQL state 22005 in SQLExecute

Is there something I can do differently to avoid this error?

```
if (isset($_POST['end'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['items'] as $checked) {
        $sql = "UPDATE oeprcfil_sql SET end_dt=? WHERE cd_tp_1_cust_no =? AND cd_tp_1_item_no =? AND ID =?";
        $prepare = odbc_prepare($conn, $sql);
        $end_dt = $checked['end_dt'];
        $cus_no = $checked['cus_no'];
        $item_no = $checked['item_no'];
        $id = $checked['ID'];

        odbc_execute(
            $prepare,
            array($end_dt, $cus_no, $item_no, $id)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24651612/4875631

Comment: In short, make sure your date/time format is correct.

Comment: BINGO...Is there a way to convert 08/15/2015 to this 2015-08-15 in php after grabbing user input?

Comment: Never mind http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306999/php-convert-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy-yyyy-mm-dd